# reading data from a USB port

Tags: c#

I wanna read temperature of the room using a thermocouple in and monitor it.I want to write my program in C#. can anyone help me?
( I prefer to use measurement studio and DAQmx)

Comment: Do you assume you only have to connect 2 wires and then you can read it from USB?

Comment: @leppie I can prove that it is possible by connecting two wires and then read it. All you need to do is a transistor(bc107) and a temperature measuring is(LM-135).

Comment: @AliRashidi: Those 2 wires going straight into a USB data lines? If so, show me! ;p

Comment: Lots of hark work is needed tough :D

Answer (score 7):

What have you tried?

As starting point, there are some libraries that can help you:

- [SharpUSBLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpusblib/)
- [LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html)

In stackoverflow you can also find some interesting questions like these:

- [`Working with USB devices in .NET`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68749/working-with-usb-devices-in-net)
- [`USB device`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552330/usb-device?rq=1).

Comment: I want to connect a thermocouple with USB ! I need data Acquziation...

Comment: @cad You have what I have in my mind ;-)