# Read/Write to RFID

Tags: c#, rfid

I have a RFID card reader device from unknown company.
I'd like to read/write to it using any programming language.

My question: is there a general way to read/write cards (using C# as example)?
             Do I need a specific driver/API for every RFID reader?

Answer (score 0):

No, but without drivers you can try to read raw data from USB device and find out what it means. Actually there should be a GUID.
Here is the article/question [reading data from a USB port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628601/reading-data-from-a-usb-port) which may help